# callback function to grab an image

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, callback, mfc

I am looking into using a callback to access an image. After calling a dll function from an MFC C++ application.  I was wondering what is the best practice in C++ (preferably C++11). 
My dll declaration is:

```
typedef void (CALLBACK * ImageCallback)(unsigned char *img, int width, int height, int channels);

class __declspec(dllexport) myInterface
{
public:
    myInterface(void);
    ~myInterface(void);
    void initializeInterface(  ImageCallback stitching_callback);
    bool combineImages(const std::vector<cv::Mat> images, cv::Mat &im_res, cv::Mat &im_res2);
private:
        ImageCallback stcallback;

};
```

The function `combineImages` will take sometime to process, I cannot let the GUI hang until it finishes. I would like to use a callback function to notify my GUI C++ App that combineImages has returned and get the output image. 
Here is my Cpp:

```
void myInterface::initializeInterface(  ImageCallback st_callback)
{
    stcallback =  st_callback;
}

bool myInterface::combineImages(const std::vector<cv::Mat> images, cv::Mat &im_res, cv::Mat &im_res2)
{
    // do some things
    // modify outputs im_res and im_res2, I want to trigger the callback here
    ImageCallback();
}
```

My GUI is written in MFC the part where I use this dll is:

```
void AutoDlg::OnBnClickedButton()
{
    cv::Mat im1_orig, outimage1, outimage2;
    // input images in images
    myInterface Test;
    test.initializeInterface();
    Test.combineImages(images, outimage1, outimage2);

}
```

I m not sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated. My question is how in the MFC code, I can get  `outimage1` and `outimage2` without having to have the   function `OnBnClickedButton` to hang until `combineImages` returns

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual question is. Are you asking the best way to write a function who's pointer type is compatible with `ImageCallback` ?

Comment: An object oriented callback in C++1x is a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) ..

Comment: Not sure smart is to mix c++11 mfc AND opencv together

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux please see my edit towards the end

Comment: @user3104201, it is not a must but I am curious, why?

Comment: "without having to have the function OnBnClickedButton to hang" -- do the processing asynchronously (in a worker thread). Post a message to notify the UI when the processing is done.

Comment: @txtechhelp, I guess a good start for me would be, how do I wrap combineImages in a std::function style callback considering the input images?

Comment: @DanMašek using events? and how would I grab the output image?

Comment: @Samer I'd say `PostMessage` using user messages (`RegisterWindowMessage`). Could probably be member variables of your window/dialog (+ a mutex for synchronization).

Comment: @DanMašek: You don't register messages for application private messaging. You control both sender and receiver. A simple `WM_APP + x` message identifier is just fine. You would register a global message, if you want to offer an interface to other applications. This is not the case here. And `PostMessage` is the wrong tool, as it doesn't allow to pass data back, and know, when the recipient has taken ownership. You'll have to go with `SendMessage`.